# how to make stream seekable in php?

Tags: php, guzzle

I use php 7.4.10 and I need create Stream which will be seekable, example I have url,

http://feed.adrecord.com/babybjorn.csv?id=395bbfcc322e

I use "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0", with "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^2.0@dev",

```
$client = new Client();
        try {
            $response = $client->request(
                'GET',
                $url,
                [
                    'stream' => true,
                    'version' => '1.0'
                ]
            )->getBody();
        } catch (ClientException $exception) {
            
        }

        $phpStream = $response->detach();
```

how to make stream with that url seekable and from what this dependencies, fro resource or from some another reason , could someone explain ?